# Strange interpretation of odds ratio from logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, odds

I am involved in writing a manuscript applying logistic regression to estimate rates of seafood mislabelling.

The model (fitted using `glm()` with the default logit link) employs source (grocery store, restaurant, or sushi bar), state (modified or plain), appearance (cooked or raw), form (chopped, chunk, fillet, or whole) and colour (light or red) to predict whether samples are mislabelled (1) or correctly labelled (0). Baseline reference levels are alphabetical as above.

Here are the odds ratios derived from exponentiating the log odds given in the `summary()` output based on converting the above categories to factors via `as.factor()`:

```
(Intercept)      Source       State  Appearance        Form      Colour 
  1.1518858   0.9112306   0.2528131   3.5247487   1.5654099   0.1954747
```

Consider the `Source` variable. My colleague writes

```
"Source is associated with an 8.888% decrease in the odds of mislabelling compared to a grocery store sample."
```

The 8.88% comes from 1 - 0.9112306 = 0.0887614.

I see what the author is doing since comparison is being made to a base odds of 1. However, the interpretation as absolute percentage difference seems off.

Thoughts on this?

Comment: Should this read "Source is associated with an 8.888% **decrease** in the odds"?  Odds ratios act multiplicatively so when you multiple a number by something less than 1, it gets smaller.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: I might edit this to talk about a relative effect.  I.e. Source is associated with an 8.88% relative decease in the odds" since the effect is multiplicative in the model.

Comment: You have *three* sources, per your text. There should be parameters for, e.g., `SourceRestaurant` and `SourceSushiBar`. Similar for `Form`. Something does not work here.

Comment: I noticed that when `as.factor()` is not first applied to each predictor prior to fitting the model, then the output (*e.g.*, from `summary()`) is exactly what you state in your comment. We're replicating a past study (which failed miserably on the stats IMHO - they only reported $F$ statistics for each predictor), but still wanted a means of comparison between our results (in R) and theirs (in MATLAB)

Comment: @compbiostats I know this isn't really the topic of the question, but you should triple-check that `glm()` isn't interpreting `Source` somehow as a numerical predictor. Normally if it's a `character`/string input, it's treated as equivalent to factor. The fact that you get a different result with `as.factor()` makes me nervous that you've made this mistake.

Comment: @shadowtalker You raise a good point and I am admittedly a bit suspicious myself. I checked the object type via `typeof()` for all model predictors prior to, and after, converting to factors. Both give the output `"character".`

Comment: The form variable seems to have the same problem. Are you sure your collaborators have saved the variables as factors in the data.frame?

Comment: @mdewey Once the raw data was read into R, the function `trimws()` was applied to each category to remove whitespace, as some categorical levels were counted more than once based on the CSV file (*e.g.*, "plain", "plain "). Then, categories were converted to factors via `as.factor()` prior to placing the results in a data fame to be interpreted by `glm()`.