# Logistic Classification using R::caret

Tags: logistic, classification

My question stems from this one I recently posted (I've fixed the issue raised in the comments, though that wasn't the topic of the question):

[Strange interpretation of odds ratio from logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630136/strange-interpretation-of-odds-ratio-from-logistic-regression?noredirect=1#comment1176114_630136)

To summarize, I have 281 samples of seafood which are either correctly labeled (1) or mislabelled (0) based on seafood source (grocery, restaurant, sushi bar), state (cooked, raw), appearance (modified, plain), form (chopped, chunk, fillet, whole), and colour (light, red). There are 4 additional samples which are missing the response outcome. I am using these for downstream prediction. To be clear, my dataset of complete cases is quite imbalanced: 211 correctly labelled samples $vs$ 70 mislabelled. I carried out logistic regression to compute point estimates and CIs for log odds, odds, and probabilities (on the complete case data of course).

Now, I would like to use the model for classification using the `caret` R package. The default decision boundary on which to classify samples is 50%. If the computed probability for a given sample is below 50%, then the sample is classified as correctly labelled; otherwise (with probability $\geq$ 50%), it is mislabelled. Based on my model at a 50% threshold, none of the 4 held out samples are mislabelled (hence, they are correctly labelled).

Now, the goal is to find a better decision boundary that more accurately balances sensitivity and specificity. To do this, I use ROC curves combined with Youden's J statistic:

$J = Sensitivity + Specificity - 1$

which corresponds to a threshold of 27.693%. With this cutoff two samples are predicted to be mislabelled. The AUC is 72.470%. The model's accuracy was 76.512%.

**My question**: Note, that I didn't split data in the traditional sense. One could loosely consider the 281 samples as the "training set", and the 4 missing response samples as the "test set". **How valid is this approach?** This isn't exactly training and testing on the same data (which would result in overfitting). Also the model accuracy is not suspiciously high (say, 90-98%). Further, I don't want to get too deep in the ML side of things, as this is eventually going to an RSS journal).

**Edit**

In the comments, @Dave brought up the cost of misclassification, suggesting that a logistic classifier is pointless at this stage. Sure, we can do classification, and predictions could be wrong, but in the end they only estimates contingent on collected data (and to some degree on the preprocessing and ML analysis techniques (e.g., 5-fold, 10-fold or LOO cross validation?) used).

I'll try to justify my thinking.

Of the two samples predicted to be mislabelled at a threshold of 27.693%, one is a cooked modified light-coloured fillet from a restaurant, whereas the other is a raw plain light-coloured fillet from a sushi bar.

These findings are in line with fraudulent behaviours in the supply chain. With an accurate binary classifier, we could potentially target where mislabelling is potentially happening: With fishers at ports? With retails at point of sale?

**Addendum**

Here is the glm output (using all 281 samples):

```
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       2.23492    1.62772   1.373   0.1697    
SourceRestaurant  0.89308    0.90106   0.991   0.3216    
SourceSushiBar    0.06103    0.39016   0.156   0.8757    
StateRaw         -1.18760    1.00139  -1.186   0.2356    
AppearancePlain   1.84559    0.80120   2.304   0.0212 *  
FormChunk        -3.57802    1.58606  -2.256   0.0241 *  
FormFillet       -3.55851    1.51865  -2.343   0.0191 *  
FormWhole        -1.57447    1.72502  -0.913   0.3614    
ColourRed        -1.74047    0.41069  -4.238 2.26e-05 ***
```

Here are the probabilities (computed from exponentiating the odds):

```
 (Intercept) SourceRestaurant   SourceSushiBar         StateRaw  AppearancePlain 
   90.334181        70.952561        51.525186        23.368922        86.360824 
   FormChunk       FormFillet        FormWhole        ColourRed 
    2.717201         2.769256        17.157955        14.925305
```

Comment: What is the cost of each kind of misclassification? Until you have a handle on that, I’m not sure you have much business making a classification instead of reporting a probability. Consider how you will use these predictions.

Comment: @Dave Not sure what you mean by your comment. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You make a classification. It’s wrong. What is the cost? (If there is no cost, then why bother doing hard work to identify the correct category?)

Comment: Classification is a bad approach for this and almost all other situations.  And logistic regression is not meant for classification.  It is a direct probability model.  Classification = decision and should be left to the decision makers who possess the cost/utility/loss function (consequences of decisions).